# Can not get examples in the book Graph Databases to work

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

From Page 44 or the [Neo4J book](http://www.neotechnology.com/2013/05/oreilly-graph-databases-first-edition-hot-off-the-press/), how do I create the indexes required for the sample data such that the queries will work?

I have set up auto indexing in neo4j.properties and listed the relevant ..._keys_indexable however in the shell I always get an error along the lines of 'index author not defined'

I then tried used the REST interface to manually add the indexes, deleted and re imported the sample data the query runs but returns zero results.

```
START theater=node:venue(name='Theatre Royal'), newcastle=node:city(name='Newcastle'), bard=node:author(lastname='Shakespeare') MATCH (newcastle)<-[:STREET|CITY*1..2]-(theater) <-[:VENUE]-()-[:PERFORMANCE_OF]->()-[:PRODUCTION_OF]-> (play)<-[:WROTE_PLAY]-(bard) RETURN DISTINCT play.title AS play;
==> +------+
==> | play |
==> +------+
==> +------+
==> 0 row
```

Otherwise this is an out of the box install of Neo4j enterprise 1.9

Clearly I am missing something here? or do I need to do this via Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks so much for asking this question, it is certainly something that some people run into, and should probably be explained on the books website.

Ian and Jim created the datasets using the Java API, so they used the indexing framework to add nodes manually.

But auto-indexing works well too, make sure to set both properties, name and lastname as `node_keys_indexable`

You just have to enable it *before* you insert the data.

otherwise you have to reindex it with:

```
start n=node(*)
where has(n.name)
set n.name=n.name

start n=node(*)
where has(n.lastname)
set n.lastname=n.lastname
```

then you can use node_auto_index as index name and it should work

```
START theater=node:node_auto_index(name='Theatre Royal'), 
newcastle=node:node_auto_index(name='Newcastle'), 
bard=node:node_auto_index(lastname='Shakespeare') 

MATCH (newcastle)<-[:STREET|CITY*1..2]-(theater) <-[:VENUE]-
      ()-[:PERFORMANCE_OF]->()-[:PRODUCTION_OF]-> 
      (play)<-[:WROTE_PLAY]-(bard) 

RETURN DISTINCT play.title AS play;
```

Answer (score 0):

I reworked the examples to use the new labels feature.

```
CREATE (shakespeare:author { firstname: 'William', lastname: 'Shakespeare' }),                  (juliusCaesar { title: 'Julius Caesar' }), 
                 (shakespeare)-[:WROTE_PLAY { year: 1599 }]->(juliusCaesar),
                 (theTempest { title: 'The Tempest' }), 
                 (shakespeare)-[:WROTE_PLAY { year: 1610}]->(theTempest),
       (rsc { name: 'RSC' }),
       (production1 { name: 'Julius Caesar' }),
       (rsc)-[:PRODUCED]->(production1),
       (production1)-[:PRODUCTION_OF]->(juliusCaesar),
       (performance1 { date: 20120729 }),
       (performance1)-[:PERFORMANCE_OF]->(production1),
       (production2 { name: 'The Tempest' }),
       (rsc)-[:PRODUCED]->(production2),
       (production2)-[:PRODUCTION_OF]->(theTempest),
       (performance2 { date: 20061121 }),
       (performance2)-[:PERFORMANCE_OF]->(production2),
       (performance3 { date: 20120730 }),
       (performance3)-[:PERFORMANCE_OF]->(production1),
       (billy { name: 'Billy' }),
       (review { rating: 5, review: 'This was awesome!' }),
       (billy)-[:WROTE_REVIEW]->(review),
       (review)-[:RATED]->(performance1),
       (theatreRoyal:theatre { name: 'Theatre Royal' }),
       (performance1)-[:VENUE]->(theatreRoyal),
       (performance2)-[:VENUE]->(theatreRoyal),
       (performance3)-[:VENUE]->(theatreRoyal),
       (greyStreet { name: 'Grey Street' }),
       (theatreRoyal)-[:STREET]->(greyStreet),
       (newcastle:city { name: 'Newcastle' }),
       (greyStreet)-[:CITY]->(newcastle),
       (tyneAndWear { name: 'Tyne and Wear' }),
       (newcastle)-[:COUNTY]->(tyneAndWear),
       (england { name: 'England' }),
       (tyneAndWear)-[:COUNTRY]->(england),
       (stratford { name: 'Stratford upon Avon' }),
       (stratford)-[:COUNTRY]->(england),
       (rsc)-[:BASED_IN]->(stratford),
       (shakespeare)-[:BORN_IN]->stratford
```

**Query**

```
MATCH (theater:theatre),
        (newcastle:city),
        (bard:author),
        (newcastle)<-[:STREET|CITY*1..2]-(theater)<-[:VENUE]-()-[p:PERFORMANCE_OF]->()-[:PRODUCTION_OF]->(play)<-[:WROTE_PLAY]-(bard)
WHERE theater.name = "Theatre Royal" AND
            newcastle.name = "Newcastle" AND
            bard.lastname = "Shakespeare"
RETURN DISTINCT play AS play,count(p) AS performance_count
```